# Expand list column into values and days with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to unpack a dataset containing columns that have lists of values. The first position in each list represents the measurement taken on the date in the "Date" column. The next position is the measurement taken on the previous day, and so on (up to 30 days back). The lists do not all have the same length, but the length of the list in count_users will equal the length in count_samples.

The goal is to get the data such that there is 1 row per Name per Date, with a single measurement for count_users and count_samples in each row.

In other words, the positions of the array need to map to a specific day, and the measurements for each Name should be summed for each day.

The original data look like this:

```
Name     Date       count_users      count_samples
A     2017-10-20   [0,0,1,2,2,4]     [1,2,1,1,1,3]
A     2017-10-18   [5,2,0,0,0,0]     [1,2,1,1,1,3]
B     2017-11-24   [0,0,0,0,4]       [1,1,1,1,3]
C     2017-09-02   []                []
D     2017-10-30   [0,0,2,4]         [1,2,1,1]
```

And the result should look like something like this:

```
Name  Date          count_users      count_samples
A     2017-10-20    0                1
A     2017-10-19    0                2
A     2017-10-18    6                2
A     2017-10-17    4                3
A     2017-10-16    2                2
A     2017-10-15    4                4
A     2017-10-14    0                1
A     2017-10-13    0                3
```

Can anyone recommend a solution?

UPDATE dict-style data:

```
{'Date': {0: Timestamp('2017-10-20 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2017-10-18 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2017-11-24 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2017-09-02 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2017-10-30 00:00:00')},
 'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D'},
 'count_samples': {0: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3],
  1: [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3],
  2: [1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
  3: [],
  4: [1, 2, 1, 1]},
 'count_users': {0: [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 4],
  1: [5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  2: [0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
  3: [],
  4: [0, 0, 2, 4]}}
```

Comment: Can you give the example output of name `D` as it shares different lengths in `count_users` and `count_samples`.

Comment: Could you provide your dataframe example in a usable format? Maybe something like `df.head(5).to_dict()` so people can play with it?

Comment: @JonClements copy it and use`df = pd.read_clipboard()` before OP updates it.

Comment: @Tai sure - but then I have to apply `ast.literal_eval` and `pd.to_datetime` to columns - no biggy, but when seeking help, it never hurts to make it as easy for someone to help as possible.

Comment: @JonClements That's so true.

Comment: @Tai they should be the same length, I fixed it in the example.

Comment: @JonClements added dictionary-style data

Comment: Oh - your columns aren't a datetime and lists already then? That'd be a good first step...

Comment: Do you have strings for the count columns, not lists?

Comment: Yea they exported from the database as strings. It is easy to apply json.loads to convert them to lists, it is more the overall logic I am having trouble with

Comment: and the parse_dates arg in pd.read_csv seems to do the trick when reading in the data

Comment: @JonClements converted and updated in example for ease of use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

little bit hard to get it

```
New_df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':np.concatenate(np.array([pd.date_range(end=x,periods=y,freq='D')[::-1] for x,y in zip(df.Date,df.count_samples.apply(len))])),
           'Name':df.Name.repeat(df.count_samples.apply(len)),
           'count_samples':np.concatenate(df.count_samples.values),
           'count_users':np.concatenate(df.count_users.values)})

New_df.groupby(['Name','Date'],as_index=False).sum().sort_values(['Name','Date'],ascending=[True,False])
Out[458]: 
   Name       Date  count_samples  count_users
7     A 2017-10-20            1.0          0.0
6     A 2017-10-19            2.0          0.0
5     A 2017-10-18            2.0          6.0
4     A 2017-10-17            3.0          4.0
3     A 2017-10-16            2.0          2.0
2     A 2017-10-15            4.0          4.0
1     A 2017-10-14            1.0          0.0
0     A 2017-10-13            3.0          0.0
12    B 2017-11-24            1.0          0.0
11    B 2017-11-23            1.0          0.0
10    B 2017-11-22            1.0          0.0
9     B 2017-11-21            1.0          0.0
8     B 2017-11-20            3.0          4.0
16    D 2017-10-30            1.0          0.0
15    D 2017-10-29            2.0          0.0
14    D 2017-10-28            1.0          2.0
13    D 2017-10-27            1.0          4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

- Unpacks each row to a dataframe and then
- use `pd.concat` to glue then.
- Finally, use a `groupby` to sum values in a same date.

**Note**, in this example, `count_users` and `count_samples` are strings and I use `literal_eval` to turn it into a list. If one already have a list, you should get rid of `literal_eval`.

```
from ast import literal_eval
def unpack(row):
    l = len(literal_eval(row.count_users))
    date_index = pd.date_range(end=row.Date, periods=l)
    date_index = date_index[::-1]  # reverse it
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": [row.Name for _ in range(l)],
                       "count_users": literal_eval(row.count_users), 
                       "count_samples": literal_eval(row.count_samples)})
    df.set_index(date_index, inplace=True)
    return df

df_temp = pd.concat([unpack(row) for idx, row in df.iterrows()])
df_wanted = df_temp.reset_index().groupby(["index", "Name"]).sum()
```

Result

[image]

For `pd.date_range`, you can tell it last date with `end=LAST_DATE`, and tell it how many days you want from backward till `LAST_DATE` with the `period=LENGTH_DATES_YOU_NEED`.

Comment: you might be missing a period in "df_wantedreset_index()" but otherwise this looks great! Thanks!

Comment: @jnard0ne fixed the typo. sorry about that! Thanks for point that out.